# Why don't DataOutputStream.writeChars(str) and String(byte[]) use the same encoding?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm writing some marshaling/unmarshaling routines for a class project and am a bit perplexed about Java's default behavior in this case. Here are my "naive" subroutines for writing and reading strings to and from byte streams:

```
protected static void write(DataOutputStream dout, String str)
        throws IOException{
    dout.writeInt(str.length());
    dout.writeChars(str);
}

protected static String readString(DataInputStream din)
        throws IOException{
    int strLength = 2*din.readInt(); // b/c there are two bytes per char
    byte[] stringHolder = new byte[strLength];
    din.read(stringHolder);
    return new String(stringHolder);
}
```

Unfortunately, this simply doesn't work; the characters are written in UTF-16 format by default, but `String(byte[])` seems to assume that each byte will contain a character, and since ASCII characters all start with a 0 byte in UTF-16, the constructor appears to just give up and return an empty string. The solution is to change `readString` to specify that it must use UTF-16 encoding:

```
protected static String readString(DataInputStream din)
        throws IOException{
    int strLength = 2*din.readInt();
    byte[] stringHolder = new byte[strLength];
    din.read(stringHolder);
    return new String(stringHolder, "UTF-16");
}
```

My question is, why is this necessary? Since Java uses UTF-16 for strings by default, why wouldn't it assume that UTF-16 is being used when reading chars from bytes? Or, alternatively, why wouldn't it just encode the chars as bytes in the first place by default? In short, why don't the default behaviors of the `writeChars()` method and the `String(byte[])` constructor parallel each other?

Comment: How about using `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` and `DataInputStream.readUTF()`?

Comment: ....wow, that's way more convenient. Thank you. I'm still curious about why my method didn't work as expected, but I think I'll switch to using those methods instead.

Comment: I posted a full explanation, hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is you are writing using the underlying `char[]` which is essentialy a `byte[]` that represents a UTF-16 representation of a string, see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).
You are then reading using the `String(byte[] bytes)` constructor, which is designed for reading data encoded with the system default encoding, in your case presumably this is UTF-8.
You need to be consistent, in fact the `DataOutputStream.writeUTF()` and `DataInputStream.readUTF()` functions are designed especially for this.
If you want use the underlying `byte[]` for some reason you can get the UTF-8 representation of the `String` easily using `String.getBytes("UTF-8")`, again, see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).
To simplify matters you could just use an `ObjectOutputStream` and an `ObjectInputStream` and that would serialize the actual `String` to the stream rather than just its `char[]` representation.

Comment: The `String(byte[])` constructor doesn't necessarily use UTF-8, but the platform default encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to think that Java does not use any encoding of its characters. Its Strings are simply the raw 16 bit char value which is the same as UTF16. The reason the "other" methods default to the system encoding is because different platforms use different default encodings. Eg it wouldnt make sense to write UTF8 which contains partial ascii characters to a mainframe which uses EBDCDIC (sp) .